# Criteria API in clause (filtering)

Tags: java, spring-boot, criteria-api

Hey I have a small problem with my query.

I need to find users with specific competences (like licenses and stuff).

Lets say I have users with competences:

- Alex: A, B, C
- John: A, B
- Steve: B, C

Requests:

- workers?competences=A,B,C - should only return Alex

  - Currently returns Alex three times, John and Steve twice
- workers?competences=A,C - should only return Alex

  - Currently returns Alex twice, John and Steve once
- workers?competences=B,C - should return Alex and Steve

  - Currently returns Alex twice, Steve twice and John once
- workers?competences=B - should return all users

  - Currently returns everyone once

Currently it finds all users with Competence A or B or C.

I need it to return users with all the inserted competences so `competence A AND competence B AND competence C`.

This is my specification currently:

```
public static Specification<WorkDetail> hasCompetences(String searchTerm) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(searchTerm.split(",")));
            Join join = root.join("competences");
            return join.get("name").in(list);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 3 results for Alex. I think your table structure is something like below

```
name | competence
-----------------
Alex | A
Alex | B
Alex | C
John | A
John | B
```

your current query in sql might look like

```
select name from competences where competence in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

You might want to add `distinct`

```
select distinct name from competences where competence in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

which in `criteria` API seems `.distinct(true)`

**UPDATE**

`IN` is an `OR` condition. If you want `name` only with all competences you should do the following (Assuming competence won't have multiple entries for a person)

```
select name from competences where competence in ('A', 'B', 'C') group by name having count(name) = 3;
```

`3` is the length of `IN` array

Comment: So now it doesn't return duplicated users which is a step forward, but it still gives me all the users with ?competences=A,B,C when it should return only Alex. It's returning all the users with either A, B or C. I need it to be A, B and C :/

Comment: Turns out I needed the OR variant after all, but the update seems logical!